# Angular Directive: Use parent class variable in callback function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I created a directive which takes a callback function as an input. This callback is called when an event `touchstart` on the parent gets fired:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSwipeRight]',
})
export class SwipeRightDirective implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() appSwipeRight!: () => void;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').subscribe(() => {
      // ...
      this.appSwipeRight();
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-general',
  template: '<main class="main" [appSwipeRight]="onSwipeRight"></main>',
})
export class GeneralComponent {
  // ...
  onSwipeRight() {
    this.router.navigate(['/myurl']);
  }
}
```

My Problem: The callback `appSwipeRight` includes a class variable `router` from the parent. This compiles fine, but when running, I get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined", since the variable is not present in the directive.

I found a workaround by injecting `router: Router` into the directive. But that´s pretty dirty, because it gets marked as unused (and I don´t want my directive to be specific).

Can I pass `router` as a parameter of the callback or is there another way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the function an arrow function it will retain its original lexical context (ie. the `this` keyword will refer to the original context).

```js
  onSwipeRight = () => this.router.navigate(['/myurl']);
```

Passing a normal function like you've done, `this` will refer to the new object that contains the function.